# AngularJS/ CSS - change colour of text depending on its value

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have recently started working on a project that uses AngularJS quite heavily. Having not used AngularJS previously, I am still getting familiar with it.

At the moment, I am working on a page that displays the value of a variable to the user, in text format. The value will constantly be changing & automatically updated on the page, and I want to change the colour of that text based on its value. i.e. while the value of the variable is less than 100, the numbers should be displayed in white, but as soon as the value reaches 100, & for any value greater than 100, the numbers should be displayed in red.

I have identified the JS file where this information is displayed on the webpage, and have added in what I expect to be the required `if` statement to make the text change colour as I expect. That code currently looks like this:

```
.directive('umwTagBox', function($timeout, fxTag, umColorFilter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        // Create an isolated new scope
        scope: {
            ...

            // Preset colour name
            color: '@',

            ...
        },

        // Tag box template
        template: '<div class="tag-box-title" data-i18n="{{heading || tag}}">' +
              '</div><div class="tag-box-icon">' +
              '<i class="glyphicon {{icon}}"></i></div>' +
              '<div class="tag-box-info"><div class="tag-box-value">' +
              '{{value}}<span class="tag-box-unit"> {{unit}}</span></div>' +
              '<div class="tag-box-desc" data-i18n="{{description}}">' +
              '</div></div>',

        link: function($scope, $element){
            // use a print to see when/ whether this function is called:
            console.log("link: function(...) called in directive.js, umwTagBox line 801 ");
            ...
            // Set to < or > 100 for testing purposes
            $scope.value = 153;

            //Add an 'if' to check whether the value of the tag is > 100, if it is, set colour to red
            console.log("'link' function running (directive.js line 918)");
            if ($scope.value >= 100) {
                console.log("$scope.value (v >= 100) = " + $scope.value);
                valueEle.color = "red";
                console.log("valueEle.color should be red: " + valueEle.color);
            } else {
                console.log("$scope.value (v < 100) = " + $scope.value);
                //$element.css("background-color", #F8F8FF); //white
    //            $element.style.color = "white";
                valueEle.color = "white";
                umColorFilter($scope.color = white);
                console.log("valueEle.color should be white: " + valueEle.color);
            }
```

I have hardcoded the variable (`$scope.value`) to a value > 100 for testing purposes. However, when I run the code, and the page loads in the web browser, I can see in the console, that the debug:

> $scope.value (v >= 100) = 153
>
> valueEle.color should be red: red

is displayed, but for some reason, the text is still displayed in white...

Anyone have any ideas why this is? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="inputNumber"/>
<span class="white" ng-class={'red': validate()}> {{inputNumber}} </span>
```

**Angular Code:**

```
$scope.validate = function() {
  if($scope.inputNumber > 100) 
    return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Here $scope.inputNumber is the input which should be bound using ng-model.

**CSS:**

```
.white {
  color: white;
}

.red {
  color: red !important;
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I quite understand how I'd apply that to the code that is already there (I have just taken this project on, so the code-base is new to me). I probably should have mentioned that there is no 'input number' as such (at least, no user input value)... the number being displayed (the variable which can be any numeric value) is read from the hardware- the software is monitoring the state of the hardware, so I want to change the colour of the text whenever the value of this variable gets too high.

Comment: I understand your concern. you can simply consider inputNumber from the above example as the value that constantly keeps changing in your project and apply the change to that.

Comment: I tried changing the lines where I'm setting the `color` value from `valueEle.color = red;` to `valueEle.color: red;`, as you appear to have suggested, but when I load my page in the browser, the console shows the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. However, if I leave it as I have it, when the page loads, the console shows the debug I would expect (`valueEle.color should be red: red`), but the text of that variable is actually still displayed in white...

Comment: which is what I am using, as shown in my OP: `if ($scope.value >= 100) {`

Comment: I think you are using css syntax for javascript. Just to be specific, if you are using CSS, use above code. Else, use this in javascript **document.getElementById('someElementId').style.color = "red";**

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clearing that up for me- I tried doing that in the JS, but when loading the page, the variable is still white when the value is > 100, and the console now shows a message stating: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`... Any idea why this is?

Comment: you must add "id" attribute to your html element and use the same in the above javascript code.

Comment: The 'id' attribute of the HTML element appears to be `.tag-box-value`- the `valueEle` variable is given this value earlier in the function with: `var valueEle = $element.find('.tag-box-value');`, so I would expect this to retrieve the variable correctly?

Comment: Simply do this.
 document.getElementById('tag-box-value').style.color = "red";
Add this line inside a eventlistener. so that it gets executed every time the value changes.

Comment: That line gives me an error in the console: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`... I don't know why it thinks it's null though- the value of the variable is displayed in the `tag-box` on the page... but it's still the wrong colour...

Comment: Have you used tag anywhere in your javascript?

Comment: Yes, although I now seem to have resolved the `referenceError`... What's strange is that although the value of the variable is > 100, as shown by the debug that's being output to the console, the text is still white- but, if I open Developer Tools in Chrome, I can see in the console, below the output `$scope.value (v >= 100) = [object Object]`, there is the line: `n.fn.init(1)`- If I expand this line, I can see all of the variables & attributes being used. I expand the `style` element, I can see all of its attributes- color is currently blank, but if I click inside the quotes of its value, and

Comment: type: "red", then the colour of the text changes to red on the page... I don't understand why this isn't happening programmatically...?

Comment: I am sure you are doing it wrong. Have you correctly implemented the code as I have given above? You will have to use **ng-class={'red': validate()}** so that compiler checks every time the value is changed and the view is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTML` attributes as `max`, `min` to better validation on your inputs, in this sample if your value is great than `100`, `inputNumber` will `undefined` so `class=red` not applied.

```
<input type="number" max="100" ng-model="inputNumber"/>
<span class="white" ng-class="{'red': inputNumber}" ng-bind="inputNumber"></span>
```